# Getting a NullPointerException through p:ajax listener

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces

I have app.xhtml and there is a data table and panels. I'm using Apache Tomcat server. I deployed the project and there was no problem with this datatable select listener. But the project has been deployed for a week and I got a `NullPointerException` in datatable row select listener afterwards. When I restarted the Tomcat, the problem was solved itself. This problem occurs on every 7, 8 days period and restarting Tomcat solves this problem.
Data table is lazy and there is Person and Applications classes. Every person has many applications.

Below, some part of app.xhtml

```
<p:dataTable id="appDataTable"
             var="applications"
             value="#{appView.applicationLazy}"
             rowKey="#{applications.id}"
             paginator="true" rows="20"
             emptyMessage="#{"No Record"}"
             currentPageReportTemplate=" #{"Page"} ({currentPage}/{totalPages})"

             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}
             {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink}
             {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}
             {RowsPerPageDropdown}"

             rowsPerPageTemplate="20,50,100"
             lazy="true"
             selection="#{appView.selectedApplication}" selectionMode="single">

    <p:ajax event="rowSelect"
            onstart="ustPanel.collapse();"
            update="detailPanel"
            listener="#{appView.datatableRowSelectListener()}"/>
    <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="detailPanel"/>


    <f:facet name="header">
        #{"Applications"}
    </f:facet>
    <p:column headerText="#{"name"}"
              sortBy="#{appView.person.name}"
              filterBy="#{appView.person.name}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{appView.person.name}" >
        </h:outputText>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="#{"surname"}"
              sortBy="#{appView.person.surname}"
              filterBy="#{appView.person.surname}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{appView.person.surname}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="#{"mobilePhone"}"
              sortBy="#{appView.person.mobilePhone}"
              filterBy="#{appView.person.mobilePhone}"
              >
        <h:outputText value="#{appView.person.mobilePhone}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column headerText="#{"date"}"
              sortBy="#{appView.date}"
              filterBy="#{appView.date}" >
        <h:outputText value="#{appView.showDate(applications.date)}" />

    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        #{"total records"}: #{appView.applicationLazy.rowCount}
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Also here some part of AppView bean class;

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AppView extends BaseView implements Serializable {

    private Applications selectedApplication;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String mobile;
    private String date;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

        applicationLazy = new LazyDataModel<Basvurular>() {
            @Override
            public List<Applications> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String, String> filters) {
                applicationLazy.setRowCount(commonService.applicationsProjection(filters));
                return commonService.applicationsLazyLoad(first, pageSize, sortField, sortOrder, filters);
            }
        };
    }

    public void datatableRowSelectListener() {

        try {
            Locale loc = new Locale("tr", "TR");

            date = selectedApplication.getDate();
            name = selectedApplication.getPerson().getName().toUpperCase(loc);
            surname = selectedApplication.getPerson().getSurname().toUpperCase(loc);
            mobile = selectedApplication.getPerson().getMobilePhone();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

Here the exception on Tomcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.el.ELException: /app.xhtml @55,173 listener="#{appView.datatableRowSelectListener()}": java.lang.NullPointerException


at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:111)
    at 

org.primefaces.component.behavior.ajax.AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.processAjaxBehavior(AjaxBehaviorListenerImpl.java:53)
    at 

org.primefaces.event.SelectEvent.processListener(SelectEvent.java:40)
    at javax.faces.component.behavior.BehaviorBase.broadcast(BehaviorBase.java:102)
    at 

javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:769)
    at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:893)
    at 

javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:915)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:787)
    at 

javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1252)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute

(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute

(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:508)
    at
```

Comment: You've got a clear logging problem here, apart from the JSF related one. The JSF logs suggest the null pointer is happening somewhere in your own code (`InvokeApplication` phase). However, all you do there is to log the possible exceptions in the standard output (using `ex.printStackTrace()`), but not in the log file. So, there's some issue happening there but you can't see what's going on :-( So... Use a proper logging framework!

Comment: Post your full stacktrace here, including the "Caused By:"

Comment: Check your selectedApplication. Its attribute person. name, surename or mobile phone is null. Put breakpoint inside datatableRowSelectListener and debug it